# How to update the hostname automatically?

Tags: linux, hostname

When out system starts up, the default hostname is 'system', the login prompt is like this:

```
sytem login:
```

And now there is an application running and will set the hostname as `system_<mac address>` with the `sethostname()` function.

The login prompt will not be changed to `System_<mac address> login:` until user presses the enter key.

So is there any way the login prompt can be changed automatically without pressing enter key?

Note:
The hostname should be changed by the applications and the application will set the mac address to the hostname.
The system is based on GNU/Linux compiled by yacto running for powerpc.

Comment: Is that system connected to a DHCP server? You can let the DHCP set the hostname automatically.

Comment: No, our system support configure ip address manually. During the startup, the ip address is not configured yet. I think maybe I can kill the getty process, this may change the prompt, but seem too rough

Comment: Does the hostname need to change? Why not set it once and let it be? Can you share more information about your system? Distro etc.?

Comment: The should be a requirement of the product. It is implemented by this way, the hostname should be changed by the applications and the application will set the mac address to the hostname.

Comment: The system is based on GNU/Linux compiled by yacto running for powerpc

Comment: Please edit your question and add that information to have it all in one place.

Comment: You will have to change the hostname before the login prompt is displayed, that is, before the getty process is started. Now the prompt is output before the change, including the hostname at that time. What has been written can't be changed after the fact.

Comment: Understand, and I tried to kill getty to show the new prompt, it works. But do we have other way to do same thing?

Answer (score 0):

No.

The login prompt, once printed, is printed.
There is no going back and changing it.

This is still the user interface of logging in on a paper terminal, remember.
There's no full-screen video-terminal-aware textual user interface with redrawable labels and fields.

There probably should have been, decades ago, but I don't know of any updated terminal login system that does this.
The world went straight to GUI login, and never really bothered improving textual login to use the capabilities that video terminals had over paper terminals, even though things like PAM made it possible.

A (hypothetical) full-screen login program with a TUI could of course `poll()` `/proc/sys/kernel/hostname` as part of its event loop and update+redraw its prompt labels accordingly.
And PAM does allow for prompting for multiple things at once.